# Rails 4 ActiveRecord Module with ActiveSupport

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4, activesupport

So I have a few different models in my Rails 4 app that have image uploads. Rather than adding identical code to each of the models I've created a module that I can include into all of them.

Here it is:

```
module WithImage
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    attr_accessor :photo

    has_one :medium, as: :imageable

    after_save :find_or_create_medium, if: :photo?

    def photo?
      self.photo.present?
    end

    def find_or_create_medium
      medium = Medium.find_or_initialize_by_imageable_id_and_imageable_type(self.id, self.class.to_s)
      medium.attachment = photo
      medium.save
    end
  end

  def photo_url
    medium.attachment if medium.present?
  end
end

class ActiveRecord::Base
  include WithImage
end
```

A `Medium` (singular of media) in this case is a polymorphic model that has paperclip on it. The attr_accessor is a f.file_field :photo that I have on the various forms.

Here's my PurchaseType Model (that uses this mixin):

```
class PurchaseType < ActiveRecord::Base
  include WithImage

  validates_presence_of :name, :type, :price
end
```

So here's the thing, the `after_save` works great here. However, when I go to the console and do `PurchaseType.last.photo_url` I get the following error:

```
ActiveRecord::ActiveRecordError: ActiveRecord::Base doesn't belong in a hierarchy descending from ActiveRecord
```

I haven't the faintest clue what this means or why it is happening. Anyone have any insight?

Thanks!

Comment: I should mention I have this file in lib/with_image.rb and I'm including it properly.

Comment: I suspect that your `class ActiveRecord::Base` monkey patch after your `module WithImage` is at fault. Why do you need that at all?

Comment: @muistooshort right you are. I figured it out and added the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out I was trying to do things I had seen in various examples of modules. It was simple to get it working:

```
module WithImage
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    attr_accessor :photo

    has_one :medium, as: :imageable

    after_save :find_or_create_medium, if: :photo?

    def photo?
      self.photo.present?
    end

    def find_or_create_medium
      medium = Medium.find_or_initialize_by_imageable_id_and_imageable_type(self.id, self.class.to_s)
      medium.attachment = photo
      medium.save
    end

    def photo_url
      medium.attachment.url if medium.present?
    end
  end
end
```